# Как запустить бота в дискорде и телеграме одновременно?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, discord.py

Вот код

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from states import Form
import discord
import asyncio


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def send_to_discord(message):
    channel_id = 
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(message)


bot = Bot(token='')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Здравствуйте")
    
    await send_to_discord("Пользователь отправил команду /start в Telegram")

async def main():
  discord = asyncio.create_task(client.run(''))
  telegram = asyncio.create_task(executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True))
  await asyncio.wait([discord, telegram])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Когда запускаю бота в дс первым бот в телеграмме не запускается

UPD1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\test1.py", line 36, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\test1.py", line 32, in main
    discord = asyncio.create_task(client.run('MTE0ODU2OTg0NDc3ODgwNzM2Ng.GAEtUX._3TSPsptvM_dRggNUxK1GCBpPJOkDzuCIPUWUQ'))
  File "C:\Users\Ramil\Desktop\Telegram\MJ\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 33, in run
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run.<locals>.runner' was never awaited
```

Ошибка при использовании asyncio

Comment: Дели все на два py файла, запускай их через третий скрипт (желательно не python). Пусть это будет 2 разных сервиса. Идея запускать все в одном файле в будущем принесет Вам множество подводных камней. Как минимум Python плохо поддерживает многопоточность, так что два сервиса будут быстрее, чем запуск этих скриптов в 2х потоках

Comment: В проекте так не получиться сделать. Через телеграм осуществляется взаимодействие с дискордом

Comment: Используй прокладку, например в брокере сообщений

Answer (score 1):

Когда запускается бот discord он в бесконечном цикле ожидает события. В вашем случае вам надо запустить discord бота в одном потоке, а telegram бота во втором

```py
async def main():
  discord = asyncio.create_task(bot.run(''))
  telegram = asyncio.create_task(executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True))
  await asyncio.wait([discord, telegram])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Check UPD plsss